# CakePHP 3.0 saving belongsToMany data problems

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm having trouble saving data in a belongsToMany association. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Fatal Error (1): Call to a member function get() on a non-object in [application/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Association/BelongsToMany.php, line 854]
```

This is the piece of code causing trouble:

```
public function add(){
    $session = $this->request->session();
    $call = $this->Calls->newEntity([
        "user_id" => $this->Auth->user("id"),
        "customer_id" => $session->read("Customer.id"),
        "comment" => $this->request->data["comment"],
        "result_id" => $this->request->data["result_id"]
    ]);
    if($this->request->data["result_id"] === 0){
        $deliveryMode = $this->request->data["order"]["delivery"]["mode"];
        $order = new Order([
            "delivery" => $deliveryMode,
            "products" => [
                "_ids" => [1, 2]
            ]
        ]);

        if($deliveryMode === 1){
            $order->set("smartpost_delivery_id", $this->request->data["order"]["delivery"]["locations"][1]["id"]);
        }

        $call->order = $order;
    }
    $result = $this->Calls->save($call);
    if($result){
        $session->write("Customer.id", null);
        echo json_encode(["id" => $result->id]);
    } else{
        echo json_encode($call->errors());
        $this->response->statusCode(400);
    }
}
```

As we can see I'm trying to save a `Call` that has an `Order` attached to it and the part that is causing trouble is that I'm also trying to attach a list of `Products` ids to the `Order` to be saved to a jointable. If I remove the product ids, the `Call` and the `Order` are saved successfully.

4 tables are involved: `calls`, `orders`, `products`, `orders_products`. [Here's a visual representation of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txuwy.png). The table objects' code has been auto-baked by the cake app. If needed, I can provide the code for them. Associations: `Calls` hasOne `Order`, `Orders` belongsToMany `Products`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot save with the `_ids` key, you'll need entities with the appropriate primary key values.

The special `_ids` key is a convenience format that is handled by the marshaller when it converts data into entities. It will fetch the appropriate data from the datasource and replace the association property with a list of entities.

Long story short, do not create the `Order` entity manually, let the marshaller do it. You'd nost probably want to do that anyways since you are inserting user data into the entity wich should be [**validated**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#validating-data-before-building-entities) first, which is why you should also add the `smartpost_delivery_id` value to the data before converting it into an entity:

```
$orderData = [
    "delivery" => $deliveryMode,
    "products" => [
        "_ids" => [1, 2]
    ]
];

if($deliveryMode === 1) {
    $orderData["smartpost_delivery_id"] =
        $this->request->data["order"]["delivery"]["locations"][1]["id"];
}

// Adjust the name of the association in case necessary
$order = $this->Calls->association('Orders')->newEntity($orderData);
```

See also

- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-request-data-into-entities**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#validating-data-before-building-entities**